# OOP for data science

Tags: r, python, algorithms

I'm an R user trying to learn python. I normally create functions and do loops but I 've never created an object. I wonder if there's something that I'm really missing. **Can you give a useful example of OOP for data science?**

Comment: Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve? What specifically are you finding hard to understand about OOP? Just asking for a generic code example - without even a problem to solve - is not really what this site is about.

Comment: you can have a look at the most popular Bioconductor Packages for Bioinformatics. One of them is called [SummarizedExperiment](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SummarizedExperiment.html). Programmers  work with objects which are called, well, SummarizedExperiment, and these are actually mini-databases comprising 3 tables patientmetadata  - treatmentconditionsmetadata - runresult (This is extremely simplified) . Here working with objects and methods instead of matrices linked by "raw" functions has some benefits (although working with R's S4 object system has pros+cons)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "little" piece of python code, which is actually making an "object" of "Network", which was later used as a multi-layered neural network (sizes is actually a list of number of neurons for each layer). The code is:

```
class Network(object):

def __init__(self, sizes):
    self.num_layers = len(sizes)
    self.sizes = sizes
    self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
    self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                    for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

In out Network object, there are some "member variables", and if you have a slight idea about neural nets, then the names of these members clearly tell the purpose of these member variables.
Hope it was clear enough.
P.S: __init__() is actually a function, which acts as a "constructor", i-e, it automatically gets executed whenever the object is created anywhere.

Comment: yes, but you still can do it with only a function. I don't understand what is the gain over a simple function.

Comment: Well, first of all, you need to know that OOP is basically a "practical" way of programming. That means, OOP treats everything as an object, just like the real world around you. Just imagine that you need to create a strategy game; in that case, you can't just write long, repetitive, procedural scripts to make your way out of it, but you'll need to define specific classes.
Apart from that, OOP offers Data Abstraction, Encapsulation, Inheritance, Polymorphism, and you might need to look for these terms to understand the true power of OOP.

Comment: yes, I know about inheritance, etc. But I'm asking what is the use for data science. Because until now I solved everything with functions.

Comment: In your specific case, you won't necessarily need user-defined object, it's true that you can solve almost everything with some good written scripts.
But when i comes to python's modules, libraries, and all that, you'll need to work with object, member functions, and all that. Otherwise, you're good, even without creating object.
But organizing your code in an OOP format makes it more readable, understandable, and usable for generic purposes. That's another slight advantage.